# Removing dynamically created HTML table rows - Life Cycle / Viewstate problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-table, lifecycle, viewstate

so i have an HTML table with dynamically added rows and ASP.NET text boxes. I have the rows and controls re-instantiated on page_load if the viewstate[dataonpage] = true, and I'm declaring it as true in the method that adds the rows and controls. (I need them to persist on other postbacks)

**The problem is** that I'm now I've added a **CLEAR button that removes all of the html rows** (excluding the headers) when it's clicked, and for some reason on button click it gets an index error, or if using Try/Catch it **only removes half of the rows** (every other row). I believe the problem is something to do with that the viewstate[dataonpage] is still "true", and the data is being re-added on page load. If i add viewstate["dataonpage"] = "false" into the clear button method, the same happens but at least this way on the second click it removes the second half of the rows.

I understand this happens because the button event handler isn't fired until after the page_load which is why it doesn't work on the first click. But what I don't fully understand is why even without this my clear button code doesn't clear all of the rows in the first place.

Any help on understanding why it doesn't work, and a work around will be greatly appreciated!

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Convert.ToString(ViewState["DataOnPage"]) == "true")
                {
                    Getmarketdata();
                }
        }
```

```
protected void Getdatabtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ViewState["DataOnPage"] = "true";
            Getmarketdata();
        }
```

Below is method that creates adds table rows and controls:

```
public void Getmarketdata()
        {
            String url = "https://api.rightmove.co.uk/api/rent/find?index=0&sortType=1&maxDaysSinceAdded=" + Dayssinceuploadtext.Text + "&locationIdentifier=OUTCODE%5e" + Outcodetext.Text + "&apiApplication=IPAD";
            Response.Write(url);

            using (var webclient = new WebClient())
            {
                String Rawjson = webclient.DownloadString(url);
                    ViewState["VSMarketDataJSONString"] = Rawjson;
                dynamic dobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(Rawjson);
                int NoOfHouses = dobj["properties"].Count;
                Response.Write("<br />" + NoOfHouses);
                for (int i = 0; i < NoOfHouses; i++)
                {
                    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow tRow = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow();
                    GeneratorTable.Rows.Add(tRow);
                    String RMlink = String.Format("https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-to-rent/property-" + dobj["properties"][i]["identifier"].ToString()) + ".html";
                    HyperLink hypLink = new HyperLink();
                    hypLink.Text = dobj["properties"][i]["identifier"].ToString();
                    hypLink.Target = "_blank";
                    hypLink.NavigateUrl = RMlink;
                    using (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell tb1 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell())
                    {
                        tRow.Cells.Add(tb1);
                        tb1.Controls.Add(hypLink);
                    }
                    using (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell tb2 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell())
                    {
                        TextBox tbEPCe = new TextBox();
                        tRow.Cells.Add(tb2);
                        tb2.Controls.Add(tbEPCe);
                        String txtboxID = (("EPCETxtBox") + i);
                        tbEPCe.ID = txtboxID;
                        tbEPCe.Style.Add("background", "none"); tbEPCe.Style.Add("border", "1px solid black"); tbEPCe.Style.Add("border-radius", "2px");
                    }
                    using (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell tb3 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell())
                    {
                        TextBox tbEPCp = new TextBox();
                        tRow.Cells.Add(tb3);
                        tb3.Controls.Add(tbEPCp);
                        String txtboxID = (("EPCPTxtBox") + i);
                        tbEPCp.ID = txtboxID;
                        tbEPCp.Style.Add("background", "none"); tbEPCp.Style.Add("border", "1px solid black"); tbEPCp.Style.Add("border-radius", "2px");

                    }
                    using (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell tb4 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell())
                    {
                        TextBox tbBbl = new TextBox();
                        tRow.Cells.Add(tb4);
                        tb4.Controls.Add(tbBbl);
                        String txtboxID = (("BblTxtBox") + i);
                        tbBbl.ID = txtboxID;
                        tbBbl.Style.Add("background", "none"); tbBbl.Style.Add("border", "1px solid black"); tbBbl.Style.Add("border-radius", "2px");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Below is clear table rows method: **(this is the one that isn't working)**

```
public void ClearTableRows()
        {
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTable Htmlgeneratortable = ((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTable)GeneratorTable);
            int NoOfRows = Htmlgeneratortable.Rows.Count;
            for (int j = 1; j < NoOfRows; j++)
            {
                try
                {
                    Htmlgeneratortable.Rows.RemoveAt(j);
                }
                catch
                { }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It looks like you're putting logic that belongs on the *front-end* on the *back-end* of your application.. if you're updating the UI and not displaying an entirely new webpage, you should be doing this on the front-end. From the way it sounds, you just need to empty a `<table>`, this is something you could do with JavaScript on the front-end quite easily. Otherwise you'll end up with a huge mess.. for example, what **is** the `GeneratorTable`? Is this member? You shouldn't use members as presumably, `GeneratorTable` will exist for **all** clients, and not **per** client.

Comment: @user1538301 Thanks for your response. I'm quite new to this and to be honest I think I need to learn about Javascript and Client side stuff. However, GeneratorTable is the ID of an HTML table created statically in the HTML. The rows are added to it dynamically in code behind. I'm assuming that if I have multiple client requests at the same time dynamic objects, and ViewState will not be effected from one session to another? All of my code behind relies on information stored in the dynamically created asp.net text boxes, that are put into the HTML table Generatortable.

Comment: So `GeneratorTable` is a string? That doesn't seem likely considering you are casting it to a `System.Web.UI.HtmlControl`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to explain what's going on as you have the code written now; I don't have faith in my ability to provide an answer including the exact code changes to be made, so here is what is wrong with your current approach:

Your table, `GeneratorTable` exists for all clients. That doesn't mean every time someone navigates to your website a table is generated, it means that there is **one** table, and every client that logs in is getting that **one** table.

So if you add rows to it for one client, then send the table to another client, both clients will see the same table (with the rows added).

The problem is that emptying out a table is logic that has nothing to do with your back-end server. There's no reason for your server to be handling emptying a table, your server should only handle page navigations and AJAX calls pretty much, it shouldn't be changing how the webpage looks, because the server can only respond to each client *one* time.

What's the point in responding to a client with `GeneratorTable` and then updating `GeneratorTable` on the server? The client will never see the updates made to the table unless they're resent from the server.

You stated that you are new to this and need to learn about JS and client-side, this exercise should serve as an example of why you need to put certain code on the front-end and some code on the back-end, as there isn't really an elegeant way to do what you're looking to do with just the server.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I get it. It's irritating that I've got this far into the project before understanding that most of my code should have been done in Javascript client side.

Comment: Although It's not the correct way of doing it - I'm pretty much finished the project otherwise. I actually think even as it is the generator table will be different for each client, as I although the rows are added to it server side, the table is created statically in the HTML, and the method that adds the rows uses the values from ASP.NET text boxes, which is stored client side? So each client will have different rows as they will have their own ASP.NET text box values that they have input? Am I right?